# How to check multidimensional array without knowing which record to search

Tags: php, arrays

I am using this method to check which term_id is checked:

```
if ($type) {
        if ($type[0]->term_id == 24) echo '<div class="one"></div>';
        if ($type[1]->term_id == 23) echo '<div class="two"></div>';
        if ($type[2]->term_id == 22) echo '<div class="three"></div>';
    }
```

But the problem is that it works only when all three are in the array.

If I have in my array only two, term_id = 24 and term_id = 22, then it finds only 24 and doesn't find 22 because now 22 would be $type[1] instead of type[2].

So, I need to somehow put some wildcard "*" to include all possibilities like `if ($type[*]->term_id == 24) echo '<div class="one"></div>';`

How to do taht the easiest way in php?

Comment: Use a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: Where are you getting 22 23 24 from?

Comment: Try using in_array function. Refrerence - http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @SunilMishra That won't work, since he's looking for the value of a property, not a value directly in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($type) {
    foreach($type as $element) {
       switch($element->term_id) {
           case 24: echo '<div class="one"></div>';
                    break;
           case 23: echo '<div class="two"></div>';
                    break;
           case 22: echo '<div class="three"></div>';
                    break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($type) && is_array($type) ) {
    foreach($type as $element) {
       switch($element->term_id) {
           case 24: 
                echo '<div class="one"></div>';
                break;
           case 23: 
                echo '<div class="two"></div>';
                break;
           case 22:
                echo '<div class="three"></div>';
                break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a Map for your options and walk through your `$type`-Array:

```
$map = array(22=>'three',23=>'two',24=>'one');
if ($type){
    array_walk(
        $type,
        function($item,$key,$map){
            if(in_array($item->term_id, array_keys($map))){
                echo '<div class="'.$map[$item->term_id].'"></div>';
            }
        },
        $map
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is by using this function

```
function in_array_field($needle, $needle_field, $haystack, $strict = false) { 
    if ($strict) { 
        foreach ($haystack as $item) 
            if (isset($item->$needle_field) && $item->$needle_field === $needle) 
                return true; 
    }
    else { 
        foreach ($haystack as $item) 
            if (isset($item->$needle_field) && $item->$needle_field == $needle) 
                return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

You use the function as:

```
if ($type) {
    if (in_array_field('24', 'term_id', $type)) 
        echo '<div class="one"></div>';
    if (in_array_field('23', 'term_id', $type)) 
        echo '<div class="two"></div>';  
    if (in_array_field('22', 'term_id', $type)) 
        echo '<div class="three"></div>';
}
```